# golang: building interfaces for existing types to make code testable

Tags: go

I built the following 2 interfaces in order to make my code, which makes calls to the *sql* package, testable:

```
type Database interface {
    Close() error
    Query(string, ...interface{}) (DatabaseRows, error)
}

type DatabaseRows interface {
    Close() error
    Next() bool
    Scan(...interface{}) error
}
```

and the actual code which I want to test is:

```
func getDatabase(connectionString string) (db Database, err error) {
    if db , err = sql.Open("mysql", connectionString); err != nil {
        glog.V(0).Infof("Error %s", err)
    }
    return
}
```

But this fails to compile:

> *sql.DB does not implement Database (wrong type for Query method)
>
> have Query(string, ...interface {}) (*sql.Rows, error)
>
> want Query(string, ...interface {}) (DatabaseRows, error)

If I understand it correctly, it's telling me that it can't return a **Row* where a *DatabaseRow* is expected, even though *Rows* struct in is implementing all 3 functions that I declared in *DatabaseRows* interface.

Why doesn't compiler make that association?

Comment: Yes, `*sql.Rows` does implement `DatabaseRows`. The problem is that the method signatures are different, resulting in different method sets.

Comment: I don't follow.
I copied Query func's signature from the source. Even looking at the error message, one could see that the only difference between the 2 signature is the return value.

Comment: That is the _only_ difference, but there can't be _any_ difference, or it's a different signature.

Comment: Duh! You'd think that's obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found a way to work around this, yet, I would recommend creating a new API around your DB calls which actually return what you want.  This means you'll need to apply some judgment, but your tests will end up being cleaner after you apply a little bit of thought to your problem.

For instance, if your DB contains a table like this

```
+------------+----------+-----+-------------------+
| EmployeeID | Name     | Age | Salary            |
+------------+----------+-----+-------------------+
| 123        | Kara Bob | 28  | 1 Million Dollars |
+ ...
```

Create an interface like this

```
type Employee interface {
    GetEmployeeId() int
    GetName() string
    ...
}
```

Then create a real version calling your SQL database, and then a fake one with struct fields for your tests.

Comment: I created the interfaces the same way I mentioned in my question, but created types that implemented those interfaces and wrapped the actual "database/sql" library's types. That way, I could create (or use other's) test types.